# Not able to start android emulator. Althought space is not a problem in this case. Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I even tried reinstalling every thing but nothing works. Not able to start emulator. Below is the details of log file which shows error code as well but I do not have any idea about this code and what this error is about.

2023-04-14 19:05:46,084 [ 598827] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:184)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy64.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy64.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-04-14 19:05:46,100 [ 598843] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1  Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592
2023-04-14 19:05:46,100 [ 598843] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-04-14 19:05:46,100 [ 598843] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - OS: Windows 10

I even updated HAXM checked all sdks, disk space, even reinstalled jdks and Android studio.

Comment: Try allocating the emulator 20gb of internal memory, in the AVD manager.

Comment: I did that, still the result is same.